# How can I programmatically close/dismiss the dropdown calendar of a datetimepicker on ValueChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms

Working on a windows form project which includes numerous DateTimePicker controls.

The requirement was that on form load, that the Date controllers be 'empty' with no date pre-selected or populated.
We achieved this by setting the date to 'yesterday' and a custom date format of "". This gives us a blank date on load.

This is all good and well, however we've noticed now that when the user selects/clicks on the controller and selects a new date for the first time, the selected date is populated by the calendar itself doesnt dismiss.

The user would then need to click outside the controller to dismiss the calendar (since the calendar is mostly unresponsive in this state to any further selections).

Once he manually dismisses, clicking the controller and selecting a date the second time dismisses the calendar automatically as it should.

It just appears to be in this first state that the calendar doesnt dismiss. Possibly due to changing the custom format to the new selected format is causing the calendar to get? I am not sure..

Was looking through the events and methods for the DateTimePicker and couldnt find anything I could call to dismiss calendar if it is currently open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No repro on Windows 8.1 on my machine.  It also is not "blank" with the CustomFormat property set to "", it defaults to dd/MM/yyyy.

The Windows version matters a lot, this control has been tinkered with significantly across the versions.  It is an important control to Windows itself, the very first one that the user interacts with when he installs the operating system.  And used by the Clock applet in the taskbar.

The writing is on the wall, even if it looks "blank" on your machine then it won't on your user's machine.  Given the extra failure mode, CustomFormat is a troublesome property that requires the window to be recreated when changed, there is just no point in pursuing this.  If it hurts then don't do it.  No user is going to think that January 1st, 1900 is a valid date.  A simple alternative that jumps to mind is overlapping the DTP with a label.  Perhaps in a UserControl.  Just hide the label when a valid date is entered.  Nullable DTP is a favorite codeproject.com project.